# Кодирока strftime() php

Tags: кодировка, дата, php

Доброго времени суток! `strftime("%A")` (переданный аргумент лишь пример) возвращает символы вопроса, причем переодически, закономерность установить не смог - стоит CMS.
Прошу помощи. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

нажно делать    `utf8_encode(strftime("%A"))`

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, раз периодически, то возможно, этот файл правишь и сохраняешь в разных кодировках.